# Как удалить данные из DataSet?

Tags: c#

Хочу удалить из базы выделенный элемент.

```
kontragentBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
kontragentBindingSource.EndEdit();

this.kontragentTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(uK_GTMDataSet);
```

Выдает ошибку - `Для элемента Update требуется действительный DeleteCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с удаленными строками.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Обновление источников данных с объектами DataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Answer (score 1):

`Adapter` - это не класс обладающий экстрасенсорными способностями=>откуда ему знать каким образом вы что-то хотите удалить.

У Adapter есть свойство [DeleteCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2). Поместите туда команду, которая описывает логику удаления - это обычно удаление по ключу.

А еще есть класс [DbCommandBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2), который может вам вернуть готовые команды через `Get*`, но для его работы в таблице должен стоять первичный ключ.

Все.